# Merge multiple sources into a single destination

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, automapper, entity-framework-core

I want to combine 2 Domain Objects into a single data transfer object using AutoMapper.

Domain Model:

```
public class Service  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public ICollection<DownloadService> DownloadServices { get; set; } = new HashSet<DownloadService>();
}

public class DownloadService {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PageLimit { get; set; }
    public virtual int ServiceId { get; set; }
    public virtual Service Service { get; set; }
}

public class Volume {
    public override int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

DTO:

```
 public class PreferenceVM {
        public ICollection<VolumeVM> Volumes { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ServiceVM> Services { get; set; }
 }

 public class ServiceVM {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public ICollection<DownloadServiceVM> DownloadServices { get; set; } = new HashSet<DownloadServiceVM>();
 }

public class DownloadServiceVM {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int PageLimit { get; set; }
        public int CleaningInterval { get; set; }
}

 public class VolumeVM {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Mapping:

```
 cfg.CreateMap<Volume, VolumeVM>().ReverseMap();
 cfg.CreateMap<DownloadService, DownloadServiceVM>().ReverseMap();
 cfg.CreateMap<Service, ServiceVM>()
     .ForMember(d => d.DownloadServices, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.DownloadServices))
     .ReverseMap();

 cfg.CreateMap<ICollection<Volume>, PreferenceVM>()
            .ForMember(x => x.Volumes, y => y.MapFrom(src => src)).ReverseMap();
 cfg.CreateMap<ICollection<Service>, PreferenceVM>()
            .ForMember(x => x.Services, y => y.MapFrom(src => src)).ReverseMap();
```

when I try the mapping above:

```
 var services = serviceRepository.GetAll();
 var volumes = volumeRepository.GetAll();

 var entities = mapper.Map<PreferenceVM>(services);
 entities = mapper.Map(volumes, entities);
```

I get the following errors:

> Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.
>
> Mapping types: EntityQueryable`1 -> PreferenceVM
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[[Fwims.Core.Data.Model.Setting.Service,
>   Fwims.Core.Data.Model, Version=1.0.1.10, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null]] -> Fwims.Core.ViewModel.Setting.PreferenceVM

It looks like my mapping is wrong, nothing I have tried has worked. How do I properly map the Domain objects to the Data transfer objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here

```
cfg.CreateMap<ICollection<Volume>, PreferenceVM>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Volumes, y => y.MapFrom(src => src)).ReverseMap();
```

and

```
cfg.CreateMap<ICollection<Service>, PreferenceVM>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Services, y => y.MapFrom(src => src)).ReverseMap();
```

you create mappings from `ICollection<TSource>`.

However later on you are trying to map `IQeryable<TSource>`. While AutoMapper can use a base mapping to map a derived class, `IQueryable<T>` does not derive from `ICollection<T>`, hence the missing type map exception.

The solution is to create a mapping from some common base interface of `IQueryable<T>` and `ICollection<T>`, which is `IEnumerable<T>`.

So replace the above with:

```
cfg.CreateMap<IEnumerable<Volume>, PreferenceVM>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Volumes, y => y.MapFrom(src => src));
cfg.CreateMap<IEnumerable<Service>, PreferenceVM>()
    .ForMember(x => x.Services, y => y.MapFrom(src => src));
```

and the current issue will be solved.

Note that `ReverseMap` does not work in such scenarios, so I've just removed it. If you need such functionality, you have to create that mappings manually (eventually using `ConvertUsing` because there is no destination member).